# How to check if 2 values IS NULL

Tags: php, mysqli

I have these tables...

GROUP_MEMBERS

```
+---------------------------------+
|  id  |  group_id  |  member_id  |
+---------------------------------+
|  1   |  1         |  1          |
|  2   |  1         |  4          |
+---------------------------------+
```

MEMBERS

```
+-------------------------------------+
|  id  |  first  |  last  |  role_id  |
+-------------------------------------+
|  1   |  Jack   |  Jones |  1        |
|  2   |  Jane   |  Doe   |  2        |
|  3   |  Bob    |  Bee   |  2        |
|  4   |  Jen    |  Nee   |  1        |
+-------------------------------------+
```

GROUPS

```
+-----------------+
|  id  |  name    | 
+-----------------+
|  1   |  group1  |
|  2   |  group2  |
+-----------------+
```

As it is, I am using the following query...

```
SELECT
    (members.id) AS memid,
    members.first,
    members.last,
    members.role_id 
FROM
    members
    LEFT JOIN group_members ON
        members.id = group_members.member_id 
WHERE
    group_members.member_id IS NULL
GROUP BY
    members.id;
```

This outputs the members (Jane and Bob) who are not in the 'GROUP_MEMBERS' table as it should, but what I am trying get working is if I am on and another group `($_GET['group_id'])`, how can I show all members that do not have rows that match `group_id` and `member_id` on the 'GROUP_MEMBERS' table...
i.e if `group_id = '2'` show all members

I have tried adding in WHERE clause... AND group_members.group_id IS NULL.. but it shows nothing then.

Does anyone have a query which would get the output I'm looking for?
Thanks

**[EDITED]**

Just to clarify...

If my url had 'group_id=1'

I should see:

```
Bob
Jane
```

If my url has 'group_id=2'

I should see:

```
Jack
Jane
Bob
Jen
```

So it only shows 'members' that do not exist( with the 'group_id' in the url) in the 'GROUP_MEMBERS' table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood the question correctly, you are looking for something like I have made on this fiddle:
[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gArk6LM1ha2NXQie3bz1p1/1)

The query I use is:

```php
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM groups
RIGHT JOIN group_members ON groups.id = group_id
RIGHT JOIN members ON member_id = members.id
WHERE group_id <> ? OR group_id is NULL;'

$group_id = $_GET['group_id'];
$query = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param('i', $group_id);
```

In short, this query will select from the groups table, ensuring that we will select every group in your database.
Then we will join the other two tables completely (using the `RIGHT JOIN`).
Finally, we are going to select every member that *isn't* the specified the one provided by the URL, or any member that is not in a group.

Comment: Works perfect. Tx. Used the query in your Fiddle. Just changed to 'group_id <> $_GET[id]

Comment: @JasonF No worries, I provided an example in my question of how you might do it in PHP using parameters and mysqli. I highly recommend using this approach since it avoids SQL injections so it will be a lot more secure than just interpolating the `$_GET['id']`

Comment: tx, will definitely sort the injection issue.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use a sub-query**

> how can I show all members that do not have rows that match 'group_id'

```
$group_id= $_GET['group_id'];
$q = "SELECT * FROM MEMBERS WHERE MEMBERS.id NOT IN(
SELECT member_id FROM GROUP_MEMBERS WHERE group_id='$group_id'
);";
```

Explanation

```
SELECT member_id FROM GROUP_MEMBERS WHERE group_id='$grID'
```

this will get all the members in this group by a given ID
then you select all members that are not among them.

```
SELECT * FROM MEMBERS WHERE MEMBERS.id NOT IN()
```

this one will give members data except the ids inside the brackets
the sub query will get the ids of members in a given group
no need for joining the three tables since you are using id of the group existing in GROUP_MEMBERS and linking the  GROUP and MEMBERS

**one side note**

if you have a group name  and what all users not in this group you then will need to use the GROUPS table

```
SELECT * FROM MEMBERS WHERE MEMBERS.id NOT IN(
    SELECT member_id FROM GROUP_MEMBERS WHERE group_id = (
         SELECT id from GROUPS WHERE name = '$Group_Name'
    )
);
```

you may use `WHERE group_id IN (...)` it will work the same

This is a demonstration, I created same database with same data and tested the queries

```
+----+-------+-------+---------+
| id | first | last  | role_id |
+----+-------+-------+---------+
|  1 | Jack  | Jones |       1 |
|  2 | Jane  | Doe   |       2 |
|  3 | Bob   | Bee   |       2 |
|  4 | Jen   | Nee   |       2 |
+----+-------+-------+---------+
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | group1 |
|  2 | group2 |
+----+--------+
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | group_id | member_id |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 |        1 |         1 |
|  2 |        1 |         4 |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

I run the sub-query as above and the results as expected,

```
MariaDB []> select * from members where id not in 
(select member_id from group_members where group_id = 1);
```

```
+----+-------+------+---------+
| id | first | last | role_id |
+----+-------+------+---------+
|  2 | Jane  | Doe  |       2 |
|  3 | Bob   | Bee  |       2 |
+----+-------+------+---------+
```

similar for when you have group name

```
MariaDB []> select * from members where id not in 
(select member_id from group_members where group_id = 
(select id from groups where name='group1'));
```

```
+----+-------+------+---------+
| id | first | last | role_id |
+----+-------+------+---------+
|  2 | Jane  | Doe  |       2 |
|  3 | Bob   | Bee  |       2 |
+----+-------+------+---------+
```

Comment: Tx, but it still shows all members, despite the group_id.  Please see my edited part, hopefully I am explaining what resulkt I am after.